# Convert String to Float up to 2 Decimal places

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, floating-point

I have a php variable which contains values like '1.15' in string datatype, Basically i want to convert the string value to a Float value.

When the variable contains value like 1.15 it gets converted to float exactly, But if the variable has value like 1.10 after conversion to float it becomes 1.1 (I want it to be 1.10)

I have tried a few things but i am not able to convert 1.1 to 1.10.

So is there any solution for this problem?

and remember in the end the variable should have datatype float and value 1.10

Comment: Why does the data type even matter in the languages that you've stated?

Comment: can you please give live example of that convert data

Comment: To represent `1.1` as `1.10` you need to convert it back to a string since representing a float as `1.10` doesn't make any sense (it IS `1.1`).

Answer (score 0):

Computers are not humans. `1.1` is the result of converting a `Number` object to a human-readable format, so is `1.10`. `1.10 === 1.1` after all and keeping redundant data in trailing zeroes would be a waste of resources.

Any time you want to display the value of a variable it needs some conversion, so your only course of action to have a Number `1.1` to be displayed as `1.10` without explicitly converting it to a string (like `toFixed()`) is to hook up to the internals.

```
Number.prototype.toString = function(){
   return this.toFixed(2);   
}

var oneone = new Number( 1.1 );
// since implicit conversion to string is required it will show 1.10
alert( oneone );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lhxe1tu9/

It's not really the best idea (messing with native objects prototypes rarely is) and it only works with numbers declared using `new Number` constructor, not number literals. I think you could push it further, but the very concept of forcing the language to change its representation of numbers instead of formatting them for the display yourself seems strange.

Answer (score -2):

First use:

```
var newfloat = parseFloat(yourString).toFixed(2);
```

to convert to 2dp

then use `var float = parseFloat(newFloat);` (because `toFixed()` returns string) to convert to float again.

Comment: this renders a string as datatype

Comment: and than you end up with the variable `float` being this: `1.1` instead of `1.10`. You are still wrong